# Laravel CSS stylesheets stop working in certain routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project which uses Webflow's CSS framework rather than the default bootstrap framework. It works great for most pages, but I do have a 'profile' page where the CSS does not work at all. I found out it's because the route for the page uses a variable, it looks like this:

```
Route::get('/chum/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController@display');
```

The function:

```
public function display($id){
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);

        $following = $users->followings->count();
        $followers = $users->followers->count();

        return view('profile', [
            'users' => $users,
            'following' => $following,
            'followers' => $followers
        ]);
```

As you can see you go to the URL along with the id of the user's profile and it should bring you there. But for some reason the fact that you're adding that variable to the end of the URL causes the CSS to not work at all. If it helps at all these are the stylesheets and javascript files I'm using in the boilerplate.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><!--  This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com  -->
    <!--  Last Published: Sun Nov 29 2020 00:43:15 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)  -->
    <html data-wf-page="5fc2087d6594016e2f088aed" data-wf-site="5fc06e9787e537386fa53575">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Profile</title>
        <meta content="Profile" property="og:title">
        <meta content="Profile" property="twitter:title">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/cascade-ui.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            WebFont.load({
                google: {
                    families: ["Courier Prime:regular,italic,700,700italic"]
                }
            });
        </script>
        <!-- [if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif] -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ! function(o, c) {
                var n = c.documentElement,
                    t = " w-mod-";
                n.className += t + "js", ("ontouchstart" in o || o.DocumentTouch && c instanceof DocumentTouch) && (n.className += t + "touch")
            }(window, document);
        </script>
        <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="images/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
    </head>
    <body>


(Content would go here.)


        <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=5fc06e9787e537386fa53575" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the path/url of your asset to root folder of your site. Maybe just need `/` at beginning. change

```
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/cascade-ui.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

to

```
    <link href="/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/cascade-ui.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

or you can also change with `asset` helper function of laravel to add your full URL of the current host. like

```
    <link href="{{asset('css/normalize.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

`{{asset('css/normalize.css')}}` will be `https://yourhost.com/css/normalize.css`